# How can I pick single record from one to many relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have one to many relation based two tables `users` and `games` and there is also bridge table `users_games` (linking `user_id` to games).

I want to fetch a single record from games table based on provided game_id for specific user. I did some research and found `whereHas()` which is returning all games which are belongs to specific user. But I need to fetch one based on `game_id`. Can some one kindly let me know how can I fix issue in below script

```
$GameInfo = User::with('games')->whereHas('games', function ($query) use($request)
            {
                $query->where('game_id', '=', $request->game_id);
            })->find(request()->user()->id);
```

Comment: why are you using a pivot table for an one to many relation?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$GameInfo = $request
            ->user()
            ->games()
            ->where('game_id', $request->game_id)
            ->first();
```

Comment: Actually I am using `find` to get record and further script execute on `find()` response. I don't know `first` will return record in which format. I am returning that data as json

Comment: @ScriptLover `$request->user()` gives you the authenticated user, like `User::find(request()->user()->id)` would do. You were setting $GameInfo to a User model, which didn't seem right?

Answer (score 0):

If your relation 'games' is a hasMany() with table 'users_games', You can try this code

```
$GameInfo = User::with(['games' => function ($query) use($request)
        {
            $query->where('game_id', $request->game_id);
        }])
        ->where('users.id', <user_id_variable>)
        ->first();
```

And the relation 'games' in User Model as

```
public function games() 
{ 
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserGames', 'user_id', 'id'); 
}
```

Comment: I want to use `find` keyword not `first`

Comment: Since we are specifying the game id in the inner query of with() it will retrieve only that particular value. Please verify the code with your data and find whether this give your desired output

Comment: I am getting this error after executing above one `Function name must be a string`

Comment: Have you defined your games relation in your User Model, 
It may be like
    

  public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserGames', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

Comment: Yes I have defined as like `public function games()
 { 
  return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class, 'users_games', 'user_id', 'game_id');
 }`

Comment: Your error "Function name must be a string" is due to the '$' sign in "$request()->user()->id", here the request() is a method and in PHP you cannot name a method starting with a symbol, Try to get the user_id  value in proper way

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$GameInfo = User::with(['games' => function ($query) use($request)
    {
        $query->where('game_id', $request->game_id);
    }])->whereHas('games', function ($query) use($request)
        {
            $query->where('game_id', '=', $request->game_id);
        })->find(request()->user()->id);
```

Comment: yaa, sure. with condition load data in relations not whereHas. whereHas constraint on User model.

Comment: @ScriptLover got it or not?

Comment: please read this for more description  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading.

Comment: Still not understand